# How to handle deployment with git and preprocessing

Tags: git, gruntjs

I'm using [Roots Starter Theme](http://roots.io/starter-theme/) for Wordpress, which uses a `grunt` process for minifying and concatenating `.css` and `.js` files.

I've added the processed `.js` and `.css` files to `.gitignore` so that the processing occurs after the checkout of branches. My question is:

**How do I set up an `ssh` deployment process (like the one demonstrated [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh--net-19564)) if the finalized files are not in the repo?**

Answer (score 1):

You need some sort of build tool, like [Phing](http://www.phing.info/). This should allow you to run the `grunt` command, then copy the resulting files your to production servers via SSH or FTP.